# How can i handle Special characters( =) in XML

Tags: xml, character

I have some special characters in my data inside xml.So i am getting error to handle them.

```
<SubFilePath>http://d2coa5o205622p.cloudfront.net/newswatchforweb&amp;autoPlay=true&amp;autoRewind=false</SubFilePath>
```

"'=' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '";

I know how to handle other special like "<",">" ,"\"" ,"\'" ,"&"  but how can i handle the "="?

I am using c#

Comment: The snippet you have posted is well-formed XML, having correctly escaped the `&` symbols to `&amp;`. It does not generate the error you quote.

Comment: but still i am getting error for "=" symbols

Comment: Then the situation is more complex than it seems - how exactly are you writing or reading this XML?

Comment: If `=` is being thrown as an error then either (a) Your parser is broken, (b) You aren't using your parser correctly, or (c) The error is either another piece of XML that you aren't showing us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your data inside a CDATA block.

Or use `&#61;`

see: http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php

Comment: You are right @@Slebetman... using CDATA my problem solve.Can you please tell me one thing which one is batter to use CDATA or format string? can you please explain me... Thanks for your help

Comment: CDATA is the simplest as long as your data does not itself contain the CDATA terminator. With CDATA you don't need to parse your data and escape troublesome characters.

Answer (score 1):

If you use one of the XML APIs to write your XML, then there will not be a problem. Use XmlWriter or XElement.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an associated XSL schema, then you should also define this element with the type "anyURI", like this :

```
<xs:element name = "SubFilePath" type = "xs:anyURI" />
```

[See this book](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XML_Schema)